# Integral test with $f$ negative and increasing?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, convergence-divergence, proof-explanation

The Integral Test states

> Assume $f$ is continuous, **positive**, and **decreasing** on [$1, \infty$).
>
> If $\int_1 ^{\infty}f(x)\,dx$ exists and is finite, then $\sum f(n)$ converges and vice versa.

Wouldn't the theorem still hold if $f$ were negative, continuous and increasing?

My attempt to prove this case:

---

Choose partition P of integers, and  $k \; \epsilon  \;(x_{i-1},x_i)$ .

Then, $\int _1^\infty f $ is an upper bound for $\Sigma_{k = 1}^{\infty} f(k)  $ and a lower bound for $\Sigma_{k = 2}^{\infty} f(k)  $.

So $\int_1 ^{\infty}f(x)\,dx$ and  $\Sigma_{k = 1}^{\infty} f(k)  $ are bounded together, and hence converge/diverge together.

---

Comment: Sure. Or just observe that in the case that the sign of $f$ does not change, $f = -|f|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, it would also work if $f$ is negative, continuous, and increasing, but that's so similar to the case of positive, continuous, and decreasing that it really doesn't need to be mentioned (just replace $f$ with $-f$).

The more elegant formulation of the theorem would simply demand that the function is *monotone* and continuous. But the end usefulness of all three theorems would be more or less the same.

Comment: Does monotone just replace continuous? Could $f$ be monotone but not strictly non-negative? (or non-positive)?

Comment: @Jess I meant to say we could demand that $f$ be monotone and continuous. $f$ can be monotone but strictly non negative, for example, $f(x)=\frac1{x^2}$ is one such function.